# Downloading CSV files with PHP

Tags: php, csv, download

I have the following code:

```
$file_name="temp.csv";
$file_url="https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/equities/2017/AUG/cm21AUG2017bhav.csv.zip";
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\""); 
readfile($file_url);
```

This downloads as `temp.csv`, but always generates this error:

> **Warning**:  readfile(https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/equities/2017/AUG/cm21AUG2017bhav.csv.zip): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
>    in **C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\Stock\Downloadall.php** on line **24**

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: "**HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden**" means that `nseindia.com` doesn't allow you to download files from their website. You may need authentication before you're able to download from there. Also, you're not attempting to download a CSV -- you're attempting to download a `.zip`. Therefor attempting to save it as a CSV makes no sense.

Comment: you want to `readfile()` a file from the server filesystem, right ? should you then use a file path rather than a URL instead ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet From http://php.net/readfile: "A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled"